# VB.NET Form not showing on panel in windows forms application

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

I have a problem with a form not displaying on a panel in my windows forms application. i have created a thread and used BeginInvoke to add the form to my panel but the panel shows with no content.

if i display the form as a dialog using frmMot.ShowDialog it works but it is not shown in the panel as i require

here is my code:

```
 If dms.datanumeric("Filters", 4) = "1" Then
     Me.panelMot.Controls.Clear()
     Me.panelMot.Visible = True
     Me.lblDiaryDate.Visible = True
     Me.txtDiaryDate.Visible = True
     Me.btnNextDay.Visible = True
     Me.btnPrevDay.Visible = True
     Dim t As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ThreadProc)
     t.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA)
     t.Start()
 End If

 Private Sub ThreadProc()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
       Me.BeginInvoke(DirectCast(Sub()
                                    frmMot = New frmMotDiary(clsDmsData.Date)
                                    frmMot.TopLevel = False
                                    panelMot.Controls.Add(frmMot)
                                    frmMot.Show()
                                 End Sub, MethodInvoker))
    Else
       Me.panelMot.Controls.Clear()
       frmMot = New frmMotDiary(clsDmsData.Date)
       frmMot.TopLevel = False
       panelMot.Controls.Add(frmMot)
       frmMot.Show()
    End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: Controls.Clear() is a nasty bug, disposing the controls you remove is a rock-hard requirement.  You must set the Location and Size properties, usually best to use Dock.  Use InvokeRequired only to throw an exception, something very bad happened if it is False.

Comment: thanks, however this does not answer my question as to why the form is not showing on the panel, the panel is there it just displays as a blank panel

Comment: I created a simple sample project that mirrors what you're doing, and it works. Perhaps it has something to do with the properties on `frmMotDiary`. If you try adding the base class `Form` instead, does that show up in the panel?

Comment: @JasonTyler thanks for your reply, upon further investigation if i set the allowdrop property on frmMot to false it works, that would mean it is a threading issue?